# Jquery Fill in Form Input Text Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page load I would like jquery to load the UUID method as a value to the UUID field so that I see it passed as a parameter on submit. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120481/html-form-fill-input-with-value-if-nothing-is-entered) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914161/fill-in-a-form-with-jquery) helped, but Im still not getting there...

```
<FORM ACTION="urlAuction.html" METHOD=GET>
 <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="url">
 <INPUT id="uuid" TYPE=TEXT NAME="uuid" VALUE="" >
 <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE=Submit>
</FORM>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var $uuid = $('#uuid'); 
         $uuid.val(GUID());
 });
 function GUID ()
 {
  'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: That function belongs in a game of code golf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GUID function lacks a `return` to return the value it produces for you:

```
 function GUID ()
 {
     return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c)
     {
        var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
     });
 }
```

It looks like it returns something the way you formatted the braces, but in fact the `return v.toString(16)` belongs to the anonymous callback function being used by `replace` to populate each digit with a random hexdecimal digit.